# swapping nodes in a liveset of nodes

Tags: javascript, xml, dom

This has been a challenge for me...

I have a set of nodes in an XML doc. I need to sort them based on a certain node value. So if I iterate through the nodes, and then the node value matches my criteria, I want it to go to the end.

Problem is, of course as soon as I swap, as nodes are in a live set, the iteration pointer misses one entry of course, as the appendChild is operating on a live-set.

This is my code so far, but as I said, it may miss an entry due to the swapping:

```
for (var i=1; i <= nElem; i++)
{
    var node = getNode(dom,"//item[" + i + "]");
    var state = getNodeValue(dom,"//item[" + i + "]/state");
    if ((state != 'XX') && (i != nElem))
    {
        node.parentNode.appendChild(node);              
    }
}
```

What I actually want is that all items in state "XX" are at the top.

Has anyone an intelligent idea to this?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use array.sort() and pass a custom sort routine:

- `var nodes = getNode(dom, "//item");` gets you an array of items
- next, remove the entries in `nodes` from the dom
- do an `nodes.sort(sortfunction)` where sortfunction is `sortfunction(a,b)`
- implement `sortfunction` so that it returns

  - -1 if a shall be lower than b
  - 0 if equal
  - 1 if a shall be higher than b
- add the entries of `nodes` back to the dom

I think, that would do it (as long as I'm not missing something).

Comment: That's the best I did come up with too. Trouble is, my nodes do not share the same parent necessarily (while they should: it's a bug in our supplier...no chance to get that changed any time soon). So I can't just remove them and then put them back...but maybe I'll do it anyway (EDIT: by using the same parent)